# Coldfusion ORM get external key

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I have an Coldfusion orm application that have two object:

Widget.cfc

```
// Primary Key
property name="id" fieldtype="id" column="" generator="native";

// Properties
property name="col" type="string";
property name="created_at" type="date";
property name="kind" type="string";
property name="name" type="string";
property name="label" type="string";
property name="range" type="string";
property name="row" type="numeric";
property name="size" type="numeric";
property name="size_x" type="numeric";
property name="size_y" type="numeric";
property name="source" type="string" default="null";
property name="targets" type="numeric";
property name="update_interval" ormtype="int";
property name="update_at" type="date";

//Relationship
property name="dashboards" fieldtype="many-to-many" 
        linktable="DashboardWidgets" 
        type="array" cfc="dashboard" 
        cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" singularname="dashboard";
```

And dashboard.cfc

```
// Primary Key
property name="id" fieldtype="id" column="id" generator="native";

// Properties
property name="name" type="string";
property name="time" type="timestamp";
property name="layout" type="string";
property name="created_at" type="timestamp";
property name="updated_at" type="timestamp";
property name="locked" type="boolean";

//Relationships 
property name="widgets" fieldtype="many-to-many" 
    linktable="DashboardWidgets" type="array" cfc="widget" 
    cascade="all-delete-orphan" singularname="widget";
```

I need to output as json all the property of widget.cfc and also the dashboard id that is defined in the relationship.

So what I have is something like:

```
[{"id":5,"kind":"number",
"name":"dsfasdfa",
"size_x":1,
"size_y":1,
"source":"demo",
"update_interval":36000,
"dashboards":[{"id":3,"name":"Undefined name",
    "time":"July, 24 2013 20:52:44 +0200",
    "layout":"test",
    "created_at":"July, 24 2013 20:52:44 +0200",
    "updated_at":"July, 24 2013 20:52:44 +0200",
    "locked":false,
    "widgets":null}]
}]
```

What I need insted is something like:

```
[{"id":5,
"kind":"number",
"name":"dsfasdfa",
"size_x":1,
"size_y":1,
"source":"demo",
"update_interval":36000,
"dashboard_id":3
}]
```

How can I achieve this? I need only the id of the dashboard.

Comment: How are you creating the JSON?

Comment: I serialize the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to obtain this [in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSE01EDE03-6E6B-4669-8C54-358460778450.html#WS9BEB18FD-48F3-450c-AC49-09B872779E10):

```
<cfproperty name="art" 
      fieldtype="one-to-many" 
      cfc="ART" 
      fkcolumn="artistId" 
      lazy="true">
```